# Angular unit test get element by variable declaration

Tags: angular, testing, element

I have inputs and variable declarations. How can I get the elements by variable declarations?

#### Example HTML:

```
<input #in type="text" ....>
```

#### Test query:

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#in')).nativeElement;
```

However, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can get element by:

```
<input id="simpleInput" type="text" ....>



fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#simpleInput')).nativeElement;
```

Comment: can you check this.